# linux elf .bss section memory cost

Tags: linux, memory, elf

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
typedef struct {
    char a[1024];
} AA;

static AA a[102400];
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    getchar();
    memset(a, 0, sizeof(a)/2);
    getchar();
}
```

I am trying to understand the memory cost of elf .bss. Above is my test program. When the program starts, it uses very few memory so I think the static AA a[102400] is not mapping at all.When I press "Enter" to let it memset half of the array, 50M memory is consumed. Does this mean that linux kernel supports mapping .bss section dynamically so I don't need to care about the memory waste of unused global/static vairables?

Comment: What if your compiler completely removed the `a` variable as an optimization?

Comment: "so I don't need to care about the memory waste of unused global/static vairables". I wouldn't say that. AFAIK, the loader does lazy mappings for the BSS. All BSS pages start mapped to a single zeroed page. When a BSS page is first written to a new writable page is allocated and mapped. So it's true that it is possible that an unused variable may never require a seperate mapping. But it may also lie within a page that is mapped due to another adjacent variable and hence waste memory in that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.bss` section is mapped copy-on-write to the zero page.

If you don't write to it, it's not actually part of the RSS (Resident Set Size) of your program, because it can always be mapped back from the zero page.

The moment when you write to it, the kernel needs to remap it into writeable memory, and now you're actually consuming that memory.